# Database error after moving website?

Tags: php, mysql

I just moved my website from a test domain to the actual domain and I changed the DB info in the PHP script, but I'm still getting an error even though I triple-checked that I have the correct database, host, username and password. Am I missing something? This is the code I use to connect. The database info is definitely correct.

```
$dbhost = "localhost"; 
$dbuser = "username"; 
$dbpass = "password"; 

function dbConnect($db='dbname') {
    global $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass;

    $dbcnx = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
        or die('Database problem.');

    if ($db!='' and !@mysql_select_db($db))
        die('Database not available at the moment. Please try again in a couple of minutes.');

    return $dbcnx;
}
```

And then I call the function `dbConnect('dbname')` from the script. The error I get is the second error from the code above, "Database not available at the moment. Please try again in a couple of minutes.".

Can anyone see something I'm missing here?

EDIT:

The actual MySQL error is:

```
Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' to database 'dbname'
```

Comment: Remove the `@` to stop suppressing errors from the mysql functions! Call `mysql_error()` after `mysql_connect()` to see what's happening here.

Comment: Use of `@` error suppression is _really discouraged_. Instead be sure `display_errors` is turned on in development and off in production.

Comment: Either you have not yet created your database, or the name of the database ('dbname') is wrong. Use PhpMyAdmin or the command line to fix that.

Comment: You're 100% absolutely positively sure you're passing in the correct database name?  The connection seems fine because you get past that point.  Like @Michael said, get rid of the `@` symbols as that's only preventing you from figuring out the error.

Comment: I added the actual MySQL error to my post. Eugen, I just created the database half an hour ago, the name is definitely correct.

Comment: Are you sure both domains share the same server? Who's the web host?

Comment: They don't share the same server. Why should that matter? The db info IS correct on this server, as there's another part of the website running on the same domain with the same info.

Comment: They are on separate servers, but `localhost` points to the same server from both? I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it could be a permissions problem.

Try logging in to mysql and running:

```
grant all on <your db name>.* to <your user>@localhost identified by '<your password>';
flush privileges.
```

Comment: I tried running that in phpMyAdmin and got the error: #1044 - Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' to database 'dbname'. This beign a shared hosting account, I don't have root access.

Comment: If you can get to a CLI it should run - I dont use phpMyAdmin.  Login using your "root" user to mysql using a CLI, then : grant all on dbname.* to username@localhost identified by 'password'; flush privileges; and it should permit you to connect.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the error suppression (@) from your code it may give you more of a clue